# FileNotFoundException after exporting as .jar file

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

I'm using Eclipse and developing a java application where I use of a local file.
The file is inside the project folder, in a subfolder, say "mydata/myfile.txt"
When I run the app from eclipse everything works fine, I open a FileInputStream passing "mydata/myfile.txt" as the name and the file is read just fine.
But when I export my application as .jar, and try to run it, all I get is a FileNotFoundException in the console.

How can I export the program so that it can run on any computer and be able to access the file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi. can you copy the sentence when you load the path to the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your app is exported as a jar, your config file is not available as a file, since it's wrapped up in the .jar file. Instead you should access it via `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream) for more background info.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you

```
InputStream in=ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("your file");
```